# How to get headers of the redirect response using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, header, oauth-2.0, request

I'm trying to implement `OAuth2` authentication methods for an internal application. The process looks quite straightforward:

1. User presses "Login" button
2. User is being redirected to the page which contains `code` received from `OAuth2 server`
3. Request is being sent to `OAuth2 server` to obtain `access_token`
4. As soon as `access_token` is received user is being redirected back to initial page and a special header `Header["Access-Token"]` is being set during this redirection

Authentication works fine in this case, the only prolem I'm having is that I can't read `Header["Access-Token"]` after the redirection back to initial page.

Using `interceptors` I'm able to intercept requests which are being sent from the application (e.g. REST API requests) but not the ones during the page load.

Is there any solution using Angular for this problem?

Comment: Were you finally able to resolve this issue? I am stuck on exact same scenario, can't read my custom header on redirect response?

Comment: @Aubergine, Unfortunately, no. I had to use cookies instead...

Comment: @WhiteAngle rofl, exactly what I did yesterday :-) I believe this is something to do of angular losing context and browser swallowing headers. As redirect response forces browser to fetch the view(html whatever) before angular gets loaded. This is just a guess.

Comment: @Aubergine, exactly. I think the same. As far as page is being refreshed, all context is lost. And Angular performs bootstrapping from a clean sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will be helpful.

- you can redirect user to **"originalURL/"+access_token** from server as the response will be indirectly sent to endpoint on server
- Then if you don't want to expose the access_token you can set it's value in cookies/session and just remove it from url.
- **Alert**: if that token contains "/" or "#" please replace it with some keyword while redirection from server because Angular use "/" and "#" in routing. So if your url includes such characters it will redirect you to default route.