# Angular does not read all headers? Added cross domain header - zero effect, does not even read the cross domain header itself

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I have a simple interceptor trying to read custom header, not cross domain use case but whatever it's angular so I've included infamous 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' header and still zero effect.

**The response is redirect response.** This is similar:

[How to get headers of the redirect response using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605434/how-to-get-headers-of-the-redirect-response-using-angularjs)

```
app.service('accessTokenInterceptor', function($rootScope, $injector) {
        var service = this;

        service.request = function(config) {
            return config;
        };

        service.response = function(response) {

            if(response.headers('X-auth')){
                console.log("Found X-Auth" + response.headers('X-auth'));
            }

            console.log("Hello BOSS");
            // do something on success
            return response;
        };

        service.responseError = function(response) {
            return response;
        };
    });
```

On debug within service.response I get following results:
[image]

It didn't include at least three headers including the very 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'- which one of thousand angular pitfalls I am in? This is mental as all the problems relating to that seem to be resolved by including the header?

Could anyone please explain what is going? - stuck for hours.

**This is something to do with the redirect response type, I tried normal ajax request with 200 status as response,I can see custom header in this interceptor without even adding this cors header .
It does feel like some headers are being processed by browser and not given to angular in case of 302 response.**

Comment: Are you trying to build web service backend with angular?

Comment: Usually you need to configure the backend endpoint to accept cross domain requests.

Comment: it's tricky,  I have a button sign in with facebook, this button makes a request directly to server (this is to escape angular knowing too much about auth flow) , server then redirects to facebook, facebook redirects back to server, server does some work to obtain access token and then redirects to root of application path. When the redirection to root happens, internal server framework simply serves index.html as static resource, then angular kicks in but I think by the time it kicks the original redirect response details are lost as angular is loaded after server redirect happens.

Comment: @snoof I don't know if I can explain better than that. But in summary I understand that the angular context is lost when I leave to facebook and when I come back browser receives redirect response to '/' WITH the custom headers, and then makes extra call to obtain index.html as only index.html will load angular back.

The solution to that is backend generated index.html page (old style .asp/.jsp/.php which puts the token directly into the DOM or hidden param - which is what I am doing atm. Can't think anything better and that, it's mind blowing for me. :-)

Comment: the real power of angular stand out in single page application, I recommend you to research about login solution with angular. "Oauth angular".

Comment: I am not sure how delegating OAuth to angular will help me, for years of development and series of pen tests through pain I learnt never to trust client authenticity of data. Backend authentication in my case is integrated with OAuth, I don't think I can trust angular telling backend that "user is authenticated". Unless this is hybrid solution which is not dramatically different from what I am doing now :-)

Comment: I meant for a solution of combining Oauth with server side. I totally agree with you about this issue.